# How good do my questions have to be so that I don't lose my asking privilege?

Tags: support

A friend of mine once lost his ability to ask questions because he kept asking questions that were not scored high enough in proportion to his answers (he actually didn't post any answers). I've got a few hundred reputation points and nowadays I tend to ask much more questions than I post answers. My questions rarely get modded down though - should I worry about losing my privilege to ask the questions?

(as another example, I gained my ~300 points of reputation on security.stackexchange.com mainly because I asked questions, some of them are considered good. Should I worry?)

Comment: If you can ask questions that are good enough to earn 300 reputation on Security, you probably don't have anything to worry about.

Comment: It's enough to just be curious and creative there. :P Also, it's 300 in total, not for a single question.

Comment: You only need to worry if lots of your questions have negative scores (and/or lots are closed)

Comment: Looking at your profile I'd be staggered if you lost your question asking ability.  At this point I think you'd have to actively try to be terrible over a prolonged period

Comment: Also, just to be clear; you could ask a 1000 questions without ever answering one and that would be fine (as long as the questions are mostly good (not heavily downvoted)

Answer (score 6):

The types of questions that are problematic for new users, and tend to get them banned, are:

1. Wildly off-topic
2. Not understandable or incomplete
3. Lazy, and/or
4. Demonstrate unfamiliarity with the cultural norms of the site

All of these pitfalls can be alleviated by first reading the help center topics under the "Asking Questions" subtitle, and by lurking for awhile to get a feel for what kind of questions are considered acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't really that your questions have to be spectacular to avoid losing your privilege as much as it is about following the guidelines for asking questions. Following the guidelines will allow your question to be well received.

What revokes your asking privilege is when these guidelines are not followed (they can be found in the relative exchange's help center), and the result is that your questions are either closed, downvoted, deleted, or all of those. When a majority of the content provided by a user ends up in those categories, *especially* the deleted category, then their privileges can be revoked.

Generally speaking, your question will be well received if

- The answer is not easily found with a simple google search
- The question is not a duplicate of another question
- The misunderstanding or confusion you are having is well explained and as brief as possible for the given context.
- There is reasonable solution or obtainable goal that someone can explain in an answer

And you will avoid the question ban if

- Your question is well received
- You fix the question when there is something wrong with it
- You are attentive to users pointing out issues with the post
- You avoid deleting your question instead of improving it (*important*)